# Asterisk choose from menu while playing IVR

Tags: asterisk, ivr

I am trying to make an IVR menu in asterisk. My question is how can I make asterisk to be able to choose from IVR menu while playing the choices. And if I made a choose stop playing the menu and jump to next action?
Right now I have to listen the whole wav file and when it is done than I can make a choice.

My config looks like this:

```
[egy_mainmenu]
exten => s,1,Wait(1)
exten => s,n,NoOp(${CALLERID(all)})
exten => s,n,Set(CHANNEL(language)=hu)
exten => s,n,Answer
exten => s,n,Set(row="${REALTIME(isopen,name,q-egy)}")
exten => s,n,Set(row=${CUT(row,",",2)});
exten => s,n,Set(row=${CUT(row,"=",2)});
exten => s,n,GotoIf($["${row}" = "1"]?s,openhours)
exten => s,n,Macro(closed,"q-egy")
exten => s,n,Playback(egy-open)
exten => s,n,Wait(2)
exten => s,n,Hangup

exten => s,n(openhours),Wait(1)
exten => s,n(skip),Set(FILENAME=${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y%m%d)}-${UNIQUEID})
exten => s,n,Set(MONITOR_FILENAME=/var/spool/asterisk/monitor/${FILENAME})
exten => s,n,Set(MONITOR_EXEC=/usr/local/bin/asterisk_wav2ogg ${FILENAME}.wav)
exten => s,n,Set(AUDIOHOOK_INHERIT(MixMonitor)=yes)
exten => s,n,Set(CALLERID(name)=Egy)
exten => s,n,Background(egy_welcome,m)
exten => s,n,WaitExten(5)
exten => _[12345],1,Goto(egy_mainmenu_${EXTEN},s,1)

[egy_mainmenu_1]
exten => s,1,NoOp(${QUEUESTATUS})
exten => s,n,Set(CALLERID(name)=KGFB)
exten => s,n,Queue(q-egy,hRt,,,3600)
exten => s,n,GotoIf($["${QUEUESTATUS}" = "TIMEOUT"]?timeout)
exten => s,n,GotoIf($["${QUEUESTATUS}" = "FULL"]?full)
exten => s,n,GotoIf($["${QUEUESTATUS}" = "JOINEMPTY"]?joinempty)
exten => s,n,GotoIf($["${QUEUESTATUS}" = "LEAVEEMPTY"]?leaveempty)
exten => s,n,Goto(hup)
```

Comment: The use of Background for this is correct if its on the audio egy_welcome. Do you have any issue if you just add an extension directly to 1? Like add exten -> 1,1,NoOp(1 was detected). Also try removing m param just to help narrow down the troubleshooting

Comment: @Chris , thank for the reply, it works thanks to You!

Comment: Use of background is correct, but use of **n** is not correct at first position, also if timeout will be hangup.

Answer (score 0):

@Chris was right, it works with this method (I had to remove the m parameter in this line: exten => s,n,Background(egy_welcome,m)):

```
exten => s,1,Background(bizt_welcome2)
exten => s,n,WaitExten(55) ; this is priority 2
; you have hangup here, no next priority=3 for s extension

exten => _[12345],1,Goto(egy_mainmenu_${EXTEN},s,1)

[egy_mainmenu_1]
exten => s,1,NoOp(${QUEUESTATUS})
exten => s,n,Set(CALLERID(name)=KGFB)
exten => s,n,Queue(q-egy,hRt,,,3600)
exten => s,n,GotoIf($["${QUEUESTATUS}" = "TIMEOUT"]?timeout)
exten => s,n,GotoIf($["${QUEUESTATUS}" = "FULL"]?full)
exten => s,n,GotoIf($["${QUEUESTATUS}" = "JOINEMPTY"]?joinempty)
exten => s,n,GotoIf($["${QUEUESTATUS}" = "LEAVEEMPTY"]?leaveempty)
exten => s,n,Goto(hup)
```